# How to disable different months in each of the datepicker range years using beforeShowDay method

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I would like to disable different months in each of of datepicker years specifically the start year and the end year. I know I can use the `beforeShowDay` method to run some code that can return true and false to enable/disable dates. Right now I want to disable months Sept - Dec in 2005 and Nov + Dec in 2009 but I'm not completely sure how to do this.

When I log out `date.getYear()` I get numbers like 104 an 105 when I would expect to get 2014 and 2015 etc so I'm not sure how I can check the year to then go ahead and set the true/false values based on the min and max arrays I have created that will hold the months I want to exclude.

**JS**

```
var minYear = 2005,
    maxYear = 2009,
    excludeMinYearMonths = [8, 9, 10, 11],
    excludeMaxYearMonths = [10, 11];

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: minYear + ':' + maxYear,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

            console.log(date.getYear());

            if (date.getYear() === minYear) {
                if ($.inArray(date.getMonth(), excludeMinYearMonths) > -1) {
                    return [false, ''];
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }

            if (date.getYear() === maxYear) {
                if ($.inArray(date.getMonth(), excludeMaxYearMonths) > -1) {
                    return [false, ''];
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }

        },
        defaultDate: '01/01/05'
    });
```

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qA9NT/18/

Comment: You can start by reading a documentation of [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear)! There you will see why `getFullYear()` is used instead

Comment: @Alexander thanks for pointing me in the direction of this, are there any other bits of advice you can offer?

Comment: Sure. I have posted an answer instead below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by reading a documentation of [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear). There you will see why [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) is used instead.

> The **`getYear()`** method returns the year minus 1900 in the specified date according
>   to local time. Because **`getYear()`** does not return full years, it is no longer used and has been replaced by the
>   **`getFullYear()`** method.

Also, you forgot to define a default behavior for the non-excluded dates.

```
var minYear = 2005, maxYear = 2009, excludedMonths = {
    2005: [8, 9, 10, 11],
    2009: [10, 11]
};

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: minYear + ':' + maxYear,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if (excludedMonths.hasOwnProperty(date.getFullYear())) {
            if ($.inArray(date.getMonth(), excludedMonths[date.getFullYear()]) > -1) {
                return [false, ''];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    },
    defaultDate: '01/01/05'
});
```

[Check the updated live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2y2m2/)